# Pinterest style grids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little problem, how to make divs to align in pinterest style?
Not sure how to rescribe it, but, i have it like:
[image]

and it should be like

[image]

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to use a plugin such as **packery** or **masonry** which utilises Javascript to create the complex grid structure:

Some plugins here:

http://packery.metafizzy.co/

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html

http://masonry.desandro.com/